# Why texts in <h4> and <p> elements does not appear together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've some strange problems with my code and I don't know why.

1. text in the `<p>` tag does not appear when text in `<h4>` appears and vice versa.
2. I can't select them with their classes (with jquery).

the code was working with *incremental id* attribute.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function() {
        $("main").append('<div class="card new" style="width: 20rem;">\
        <div class="layer"></div>\
            <div class="card-block">\
                <h4 class="card-title></h4>\
                <p class="card-text"></p>\
            </div>\
            <div class="card-block">\
                <div class="delete">Del</div>\
                <div class="edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#note">edit</div>\
            </div>\
        </div>');
        var title = $("#noteTitle").val();
        var text = $("#noteBody").val();

        $(".layer").css({"background-color": "yellow", "position": "absolute", "opacity": ".1", "top":"0", "left":"0", "width": "100%", "height": "100%"});
        $(".new h4").html(title);
        $(".new p").html(text);
        $(".card").removeClass("new");
    });
});
```

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen you can create multi-line strings in JS this way

Comment: `<div class="layer"></div>\` why the \ at the end?

Comment: explain clearly your question for better answer

Comment: @IrshadJm otherwise the newline would result in a syntax error. Only in template strings an unescaped newline is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the closing quotes:

```
<h4 class="card-title></h4>
```

should be:

```
<h4 class="card-title"></h4>
```

Comment: Nicely spotted, but if this is the only mistake and adding missing quote will solve it, should we not close it as a typographical problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing end quote in `h4` tag:

```
       <div class="card-block">\
            <h4 class="card-title"></h4> // missing " after class name
            <p class="card-text"></p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think problem while assigning text to `h4` and `p` tag and also you've syntax error missing the closing quotes too:

Here is working snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add").click(function() {
    $("main").append('<div class="card new" style="width: 20rem;">\
        <div class="layer"></div>\
            <div class="card-block">\
                <h4 class="card-title"></h4>\
                <p class="card-text"></p>\
            </div>\
            <div class="card-block">\
                <div class="delete">Del</div>\
                <div class="edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#note">edit</div>\
            </div>\
        </div>');
    var title = $("#noteTitle").val();
    var text = $("#noteBody").val();

    $(".new h4").html(title);
    $(".new p").html(text);
    $(".card").removeClass("new");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="noteTitle">
<input id="noteBody">
<button id="add">Add</button>
<main></main>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're also missing a hashtag for the `main` element's query: `$("main")` should be `$("#main")`.